# Should Quadtrees store points only in the children?

Tags: java, algorithm, quadtree

Though we usually define a *capacity* for each Quadtree, It seems like all the pseudo-code algorithms I find online don't care much for the **visual number of points** inside a Quadtree.

Is it necessary to redistribute the points contained by a Quadtree into its children when it's being divided?

I can't seem to implement that correctly, and the pseudo-code category of Wikipedia's Quadtree only has a comment about this (but no code):

> We have to add the points/data contained into this quad array to the new quads if we want that only the last node holds the data

Comment: Not really a question for Stackoverflow (at least not without some more indications that you searched more than just wikipedia), but hey, have some links to Daniel Shiffman explaining and live-implementing Quad Trees over on the Coding Train youtube channel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJxEcs0w_kE, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQx_NmCIuCY, and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0YFFg_nBjw

Comment: I've watched all three of his tutorials throughout and he's the one that got me asking because he didn't implement what I'm talking about in his code

Comment: Redistributing is mostly a matter of "do _you_ need to?" because the only difference is whether or not your tree lets you "exit early" rather than traversing to leaf nodes. Computationally, it makes no appreciable difference right up to the point where it does, because of the nature of your data, and the nature of your lookups. Redistribution is mostly just something you turn on when performance measurements in your specific use case show your code runs faster with it enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the question is about a **Point Quadtree**, let's have a review.

> Is it necessary to redistribute the points contained by a Quadtree into its children when it's being divided?

No, it's not necessary.

#### But, is it better?

> Redistribution is mostly just something you turn on when performance measurements in your specific use case show your code runs faster with it enabled.

Thanks to @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans for the comment.

It depends on how you're using the quadtree.

Keep in mind that,

- You would still define a **`capacity`** for each quadtree which acts as the dividing threshold.
- It won't affect the overall **time complexity**.
- More quadtrees will be present.

  Parents won't hold any points.
- Pay the price at **insertion**.

  You have to redistribute the points when the capacity is met.

What's the **impact on queries**?

- **Out of range** points are ceased faster.
- Brute-forcefully **checked points** may decrease.
- **Checked quadtrees** may increase.

Will it execute faster or slower compared to the other mode, really depends on the environment; Capacity, recursive stack overhead and points dispersion.

But, as you have paid a price at insertion time, it usually performs the queries faster.